# Merge array data and add some additional field by performing multiplication on field

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have below kind of schema

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3YbcZzqZnJb)

Problem - I want to get all succeeded transaction in list with their respective user with some extra field like reward - for that particular transaction. like if paid amount in 10 then reward will be 0.3 times -> 3. But i need 0.3 in case of 1st successful payment only for others it will be 0.1.

tried: I have achieved partial output, not able to get reward calculation based on first transaction

The output will be -

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    name: 'Stephen',
    transactions: [
      {
        _id: 1,
        paidAmount: 10,
        reward: 3
      },
      {
        _id: 3,
        paidAmount: 20,
        reward: 2
      }
      ]
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    user: 'Peter',
    transactions: [
      {
        _id: 2,
        paidAmount: 5,
        reward: 0.15
      }]
  }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i have found the solution for above

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: 1,
      
    },
    
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "payments",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "user",
      as: "payments",
      
    },
    
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      transactions: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$payments",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$$this.transactions",
                  cond: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$this.status",
                      "succeeded"
                    ]
                  },
                  
                },
                
              },
              
            ],
            
          },
          
        },
        
      },
      
    },
    
  },
  {
    $project: {
      transactions: {
        $map: {
          input: "$transactions",
          as: "t",
          in: {
            paidAmount: "$$t.paidAmount",
            status: "$$t.status",
            createdAt: "$$t.createdAt",
            reward: {
              $cond: {
                if: {
                  $eq: [
                    {
                      $indexOfArray: [
                        "$transactions",
                        "$$t"
                      ]
                    },
                    0
                  ]
                },
                then: {
                  $multiply: [
                    "$$t.paidAmount",
                    0.3
                  ]
                },
                else: {
                  $multiply: [
                    "$$t.paidAmount",
                    0.1
                  ]
                },
                
              },
              
            },
            
          },
          
        },
        
      },
      
    },
    
  },
  {
    $project: {
      id: {
        $toString: "$_id"
      },
      totalAMount: {
        $sum: "$transactions.paidAmount"
      },
      totalReward: {
        $sum: "$transactions.reward"
      },
      transactions: "$transactions",
      
    },
    
  },
  
])
```

Please comment if you find out a better solution/ approach.

[Try this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_J--0El5ZUZ)